# How to scan ports from 1 virtual machine to another?

Tags: firewall, network-shares, nmap

I have a MacBook apple m1.
I have a Kali installed on VMware fusion. I also have a Metasploitable installed on UTM.

I try to use NMAP to scan ports `nmap -Pn 10.0.2.15`, but I get such a message:

```
Host discovery disabled (-Pn).
All 1000 scanned ports on IP_ADDRESS are filtered.
```

I disabled firewall on metasploitable and on kali, but the problems still exists.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please add what type of networking you are using in Fusion https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1022264

Comment: @mtak I use bridge networking with different types - Autodetect, WIFI, Ethernet - OI tried all of them.

Comment: Can you ping from one host to the other?

Comment: @Kefka Yes I can ping from Kali to Metasploitable-2, but in the browser if I type 10.0.2.15 - unable to connect

Comment: Are you expecting a web server on the 10.0.2.15 host? Run this command on it and see what it says: `# curl -I localhost`

Comment: @Kefka If I use this command from Kali to Metasploitable - I get cur(7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused 

        If I do the same from Metasploitable to Kali - then I get this
        HTTP 200 OK
        Date: current date
        Server: Apache 
        Content type: text/html